# How to prevent view goes under UITabBar when using code to layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitabbar

I added UIViewController which has no storyboard to UITabBar.
It seems the view of added VC goes under the tab bar which does not
happen when I add a vc which used Storybaord to UITabBar.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Please provide code of adding `ViewController`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the viewcontroller extend to any edges, you can try:

```
viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

or `viewController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false` should also work